# Add NSGestureRecognizer to MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, macos, mkmapview, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to add a NSPressGestureRecognizer to a MKMapView. It works, but unfortunately it has a unpleasant side effect.

```
NSPressGestureRecognizer *gp = [[NSPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[gp setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:gp];   
[self addPin]; //Adds a pin to the map
```

It works fine, and the handleLongPress: is called. What is not working, is the ability to drag the pin on the map.

Whenenver I click and hold to 'pick up' the pin, the handleLongPress function is called. (It works fine, the I uncomment the [mapview addGesture..] line.

Is it not possible to add a custom long-press gesture recogniser to a MKMapView without overriding the existing GestureRecognizers?

Comment: What about canceling the gesture recognizer if `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState` fires?

Comment: When the GestureRecognizer is added to the view, the didChangeDragState-method is never invoked, so thats no-go. But thanks for the idea.